# Ubuntu (Linux)にEclipse (CDT)をいれたいのですが、、、

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

VirtualBox上で起動しているUbuntuにEclipse (CDT)をいれたいのですが、どのファイルをダウンロードしていれればいいのかわかりません。
CDTがバンドルされたEclipseというのをダウンロードしたいのですが、どれなんでしょうか？
なぜUbuntuにEclipseをいれるのかというと、raspi (Raspberry Pi)用にクロスコンパイルの環境を作るためです。
Ubuntuのバージョンは15.04です。

よろしくお願いします。

[参考にしているサイト](http://qiita.com/atchy@github/items/fb9df9e5865d8c7f7a72)

Comment: 最新版でなくてもよろしければ `eclipse-cdt` というパッケージがあります(バージョン 8.5.0)。

Comment: なるべく新しいのがいいんですけど、クロスコンパイルするのに新旧は関係ないですかね？

Comment: 最新版にしかない機能を使う必要があるのかどうか、だとは思いますが、どうなのでしょう？ 一応、最新版の配布元は [CDT Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) です。

Comment: やり方を紹介しているサイトが最新版でやっていたので新しい機能を使うとかはないです。
Eclipse IDE for Java Developersという名前のファイルをダウンロードしたんですが、これは教えてもらったものとは違いますか？

Comment: その「やり方を紹介しているサイト」の URL を質問欄に追記していただけますか？ そうすれば回答が付きやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: わかりました。
http://qiita.com/atchy@github/items/fb9df9e5865d8c7f7a72
このサイトを参考にしています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30045/discussion-between--and-argus)しましょう。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。
チャットでの返信の仕方が分からなかったので、ここに書かせていただきました、、、

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers です。

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
から、お使いの環境に応じて Linux 32bitか64bitをダウンロードしてください

Answer (score 0):

*Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers*をダウンロードしましょう。
[ここ](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/mars2)から環境に合わせたEclipseをダウンロードします。
(Download Linksからlinux-64bitか32bitをダウンロード)
ダウンロードしたtar.gzファイルを展開し、"eclipse"というファイルを実行すれば使えます。
(eclipse -cleanなどを行う場合はまた別の作業が必要)
余談になりますが、日本語化はされていない為、日本語で使いたいなら[Pleiades](http://mergedoc.osdn.jp)を適応しましょう。